# Best way to stop people hacking game score in post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am creating a simple javascript game where the user can win points be collecting items in the game.

When the user dies the score needs to be transferred to the server and the server then can then add them to a leaderboard.

I am wondering what the best way I can stop users just putting a breakpoint in the code before it sends the post request and increasing their score?

Does anyone have any ideas how I can best prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't trust anything done on the client. I think the best solution would be to have a *lot* of code (such that it's very difficult to reverse-engineer), make sure it's difficult to read (obfuscated), and encrypt messages between the client and the server (so that the user wouldn't be able to bypass your code by sending their own message). It's still no guarantee of safety, though.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of obfuscating, it needs to work in IE so don't think I can encrypt as the browser can't support that.  I was thinking of some kind of validation to check the timestamp from start of game to the end of game to see if the points/time ratio is off, but again I can't guarantee this would be fool proof

Comment: Sure you can encrypt stuff on IE - all you need to encrypt is Javascript, and IE supports Javascript

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding how do you mean encrypt JavaScript, there are no crypto Apis in IE, or am I missing the point?

Comment: There are hundreds of libraries that allow for encryption.

Comment: Good to know I will take a look.  This seems like it could be a winner, this game is only going to be active for a very short while so don't need anything too fancy, but this looks like it could do the trick enough to put people off.  

https://obfuscator.io/

Answer (score -1):

The way I have decided to go with this is to use this obfuscating tool online, i've tested and my code still works and makes it totally unreadable.  To me this will be enough for what I need to try and stop any hacking attempt client side.

https://obfuscator.io/

As an example, this turns this...

```
function hi() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
hi();
```

into this...

> var
>   *0x47ec=['nWQak','urEwG','SRKDw','BRVHJ','oBYts','FUjKP','ODlZT','ghsnL','nrAyC','KKMCE','LjVlL','eUxVv','DxTPw','length','LXhVN','imBSA','EEFqX','WENXH','TycqD','MwnNk','debu','nDHWM','hRvAg','cxqiw','test','uctXv','DYYJz','constructor','JkGfj','ZRfkc','GLvKV','HFujT','apply','mAOEG','NPnmv','IlYTI','init','fOjQu','call','yAGlJ','BjwwL','sqyoq','RpyHn','string','dHsIy','tCLma','chain','stateObject','VSjtN','yXRAh','saqMw','\x5c+\x5c+\x20*(?:[a-zA-Z*$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)','TMHOd','FUZwZ','function\x20*\x5c(\x20*\x5c)','OtKZF','bUNZJ','MpcMX','JDYoe','action','zXIow','eLQsB','AHQpF','counter','gger'];(function(_0x4210d1,_0x47ec7a){var
>   _0x1f5a2f=function(_0x2d1cd4){while(--_0x2d1cd4){_0x4210d1'push';}};_0x1f5a2f(++_0x47ec7a);}(_0x47ec,0x179));var
>   _0x1f5a=function(_0x4210d1,_0x47ec7a){_0x4210d1=_0x4210d1-0x0;var _0x1f5a2f=_0x47ec[_0x4210d1];return _0x1f5a2f;};function hi(){var _0x1d9184={'cxqiw':_0x1f5a('0xf'),'dHsIy':function(_0x3599bb,_0x23269a){return
>   _0x3599bb===_0x23269a;},'VSjtN':_0x1f5a('0x14'),'nWQak':_0x1f5a('0x21'),'ODlZT':_0x1f5a('0xc'),'ndGbP':_0x1f5a('0x7'),'IlYTI':function(_0x2209b8,_0x3666c3){return
>   _0x2209b8(_0x3666c3);},'urEwG':_0x1f5a('0x2'),'NzKKp':_0x1f5a('0x40'),'sqyoq':_0x1f5a('0x3b'),'ZmnER':'input','RpyHn':_0x1f5a('0x22'),'DYYJz':function(_0x51584b,_0x26c5ec){return
>   _0x51584b(_0x26c5ec);},'GLvKV':function(_0x406078){return _0x406078();},'BRVHJ':_0x1f5a('0x17'),'nqyOg':function(_0x29750b,_0x5b4d24,_0x1d374a){return _0x29750b(_0x5b4d24,_0x1d374a);}};var _0x523935=function(){var _0x59e204={'LXhVN':function(_0x472cc8,_0x567804){return _0x472cc8!==_0x567804;},'oBYts':_0x1d9184[_0x1f5a('0x24')]};if(_0x1d9184_0x1f5a('0x39')){return![];}else{var
>   _0x53f0f6=!){var
>   _0x3a9e1d=firstCall?function(){if(fn){var _0x160443=fn_0x1f5a('0x2d');fn=null;return _0x160443;}}:function(){};firstCall=;_0x5372d8=null;return _0x2683a6;}}}:function(){};_0x53f0f6=_0x1f5a('0x33'));}else{_0x1d9184['nqyOg'](_0x523935,this,function(){var
>   _0x5ba386={'KKMCE':function(_0x4360ad,_0x36a736){return _0x1d9184_0x1f5a('0x30');}};var _0x5ac246=new RegExp(_0x1d9184[_0x1f5a('0xe')]);var _0x3800df=new
>   RegExp(_0x1d9184['NzKKp'],'i');var
>   _0x3e6ebf=yYcSC(_0x1f5a('0x31'));if(!_0x5ac246_0x1f5a('0x25')||!_0x3800df_0x1f5a('0x25')){if(_0x1d9184_0x1f5a('0x39')){_0x1d9184_0x1f5a('0x27');}else{IcEIoj_0x1f5a('0x16');}}else{_0x1d9184_0x1f5a('0x2b');}})();}}());console'log';}hi();function
>   yYcSC(_0x235704){var
>   _0x47e908={'uctXv':function(_0xc4a029,_0x16818b){return _0xc4a029!==_0x16818b;},'eLQsB':_0x1f5a('0x8'),'mAOEG':_0x1f5a('0x23'),'TycqD':'Odpgi','TMHOd':function(_0x1dddfa,_0x48612f){return
>   _0x1dddfa===_0x48612f;},'eUxVv':'while\x20(true)\x20{}','HFujT':_0x1f5a('0x5'),'ZRfkc':function(_0x2f44d4,_0x5d17b4){return
>   _0x2f44d4!==_0x5d17b4;},'fOjQu':function(_0xa4360d,_0x5a8b83){return _0xa4360d+_0x5a8b83;},'FUZwZ':function(_0x354fba,_0x1d82fe){return _0x354fba/_0x1d82fe;},'EEFqX':_0x1f5a('0x1a'),'FUjKP':function(_0x4e90a1,_0x2b0dbc){return
>   _0x4e90a1+_0x2b0dbc;},'saqMw':'debu','tCLma':_0x1f5a('0xc'),'zbnjc':function(_0x28b996,_0x39f05a){return
>   _0x28b996+_0x39f05a;},'DxTPw':_0x1f5a('0x3c'),'JkGfj':function(_0x294a9c,_0x807429){return
>   _0x294a9c(_0x807429);},'bUNZJ':function(_0x1abddc,_0x2b9078){return _0x1abddc(_0x2b9078);},'WENXH':_0x1f5a('0x34'),'BjwwL':_0x1f5a('0x6'),'MwnNk':_0x1f5a('0x15')};function
>   _0x1e8ccf(_0x21fb35){var _0xa066a8={'imBSA':function(_0x199641){return _0x199641();},'yXRAh':_0x1f5a('0x3'),'NPnmv':_0x47e908[_0x1f5a('0x1f')]};if(_0x47e908['TMHOd'](typeof
>   _0x21fb35,_0x1f5a('0x38'))){return function(_0x2da2a5){}_0x1f5a('0x28')_0x1f5a('0x2d');}else{if(_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x0')){_0xa066a8_0x1f5a('0x1c');}else{if(_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x2a')||_0x21fb35%0x14===0x0){(function(){if(_0xa066a8[_0x1f5a('0x3e')]===_0xa066a8[_0x1f5a('0x2f')]){return!_0x1f5a('0x33'));}else{(function(){if(_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x26')){return![];}else{return
>   _0x1e8ccf;}}_0x1f5a('0x28')_0x1f5a('0x2d'));}}}_0x1e8ccf(++_0x21fb35);}try{if(_0x47e908['WENXH']===_0x47e908[_0x1f5a('0x1e')]){if(_0x235704){if(_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x0')){if(_0x235704){return
>   _0x1e8ccf;}else{_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x29');}}else{return
>   _0x1e8ccf;}}else{_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x4');}}else{_0x47e908_0x1f5a('0x4');}}catch(_0x2c3efb){}}

Obviously this will add some overhead to my app but it seems to be working just fine so I am happy with this solution.